# Get count of GAE class collection_name in Django Template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Google App Engine with python 2.7 and Django templates.

My object model is set up like this:

```
Class parent(db.Model):
  parentName = db.StringProperty()

Class child(db.Mode):
  childName = db.StringProperty()
  parent = db.ReferenceProperty(parent, collection_name='children')
```

My python code passes all the parents to the template

```
qry_parents = parent.all()
parents = qry_parents.fetch(30)
template_values = {'parents':parents}

self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Now, what I am trying to do, but can't seem to figure out, is how to display a count of the children from the implied collection "children" in the parent object. Here is a sample of my template.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <table>
  {% for p in parents %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ p.parentName }}</td>
      <td>{{ p.children.items|length }}</td> <!-- always zero! -->
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to reference the right thing to get the count of children out of there. I feel like I'm close, because I'm getting zero, not None or null. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `items`. `children` is a `db.Query` object already. You're best off doing `p.children.count` though.

Comment: Thanks much. I was overthinking it!